# How can I make my array print out in uppercase letters?

Tags: php

Hey everyone I'm currently trying to finish my course on code academy but i'm stuck. My task is to make a little game that randomly selects a winner from my array elements which contain names of friends.

I have it all working but I need it to print out in uppercase letters. How can I do this? What would the code look like. Here is the code i have now:

```
    <?php
$friends=array("Nando","Evan","Ron","Aleks");
array_push($friends,"Jacob","kyle");


sort($friends);

count($friends);

$winner=array_rand($friends,1);


print "<p>$friends[$winner]</p>"









?>
```

Comment: Google: `PHP strtoupper()` (BTW: `count($friends);` is completely useless here)

Answer (score 3):

How about doing a **strtoupper** to do that?

```
<?php
$friends=array("Nando","Evan","Ron","Aleks");
array_push($friends,"Jacob","kyle");
sort($friends);
// you don't need it because you are not using it
// count($friends);

$winner=array_rand($friends,1);
print '<p>'.strtoupper($friends[$winner]).'</p>';
?>
```

I think that would do what you are trying to do.